# Test class showing "Test already started" error

Tags: apex

I wrote an APEX web service, that works fine. I started writing its test class. When I run the test class, all three of my methods are failing because in between the start and stopTest callout, it shows error of "System.FinalException" Testing already started." I researched that you can have one start and stop callout in a method so thats why I seperated it into 3 different methods. But I am still getting an error.
Here is my APEX class:

Here is my test class for it:

```
@isTest
public class CC_SNOWServiceYASTest {
    
    @TestSetup static void setupData(){
        Case testCaseSNOW = new Case();
        Id yasRT = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('YAS Team Case').getRecordTypeId();
        testCaseSNOW.Origin = 'Email';
        testCaseSNOW.Status = 'Open';
        testCaseSNOW.Service_Now_Team_Assignment__c = 'LNSS Yearbook Dev 2.0';
        testCaseSNOW.RecordTypeId = yasRT;
        insert testCaseSNOW;
        system.assertNotEquals(null, testCaseSNOW.Id);
        
        Service_Ticket__c testTicket = new Service_Ticket__c();
        testTicket.Name = 'INC0611230';
        testTicket.Case_Number__c = testCaseSNOW.Id;
        testTicket.Status__c = 'Open';
        insert testTicket;
        system.assertNotEquals(null, testTicket.Id);
        
        Service_Ticket_Task__c newTestTask = new Service_Ticket_Task__c();
        newTestTask.Name = '12345';
        newTestTask.Service_Ticket__c = testTicket.Id;
        newTestTask.State__c = 'Open';
        insert newTestTask;
        system.assertNotEquals(null, newTestTask.Id);

    }
    
    @isTest
    static void getTicketsTest(){
        List<Service_Ticket__c> st = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Service_Ticket__c where Name = 'INC0611230'];
        
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/SNOWtickets';
        
        req.addParameter('Name', String.valueOf(st[0].Name));
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;
        
        Test.startTest();
            CC_SNOWServiceYAS.getServiceTicket();
        Test.startTest();
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void testPostMethod(){
        String jsonMsg = '[{"ticketName" : "INC0611231", "taskNumber" : "12345", "assignedTo" : "Bigfoot"}, {"ticketName" : "INC0611232", "taskNumber" : "123456", "assignedTo" : "Bigfoot Jr."}]';
        
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        
        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/SNOWtickets';  //Request URL
        req.httpMethod = 'POST';//HTTP Request Type
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(jsonMsg);
        
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;
        
        Test.startTest();
            CC_SNOWServiceYAS.createServiceTicketTask();
        Test.startTest();
    }
    
   @isTest
    static void testPutMethod(){
        String jsonMsg = '[ {"ticketName" : "INC0611230", "Status" : "Closed", "workNotes" : "This is case is closed", "taskStatus" : "Closed", "taskComments" : "The task is closed"}]';
        
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        
        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/SNOWtickets';  //Request URL
        req.httpMethod = 'PUT';//HTTP Request Type
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(jsonMsg);
        
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;
        
        Test.startTest();
            CC_SNOWServiceYAS.updateServiceTicket();
        Test.startTest();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The last line should be `Test.stopTest`:

```
    Test.startTest();
        CC_SNOWServiceYAS.getServiceTicket();
    Test.stopTest();
```

It's a pretty easy mistake to make.